# Remove window frame of a program

Tags: window-decorations, devilspie

Is it possible to start a program without its window frame? 
For example: start flash standalone on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 sp2 machine without its window frame so it looks like when I start a browser and remove it's window-decoration and show the flash with the browser plugin.

We could use the browser but the browser on SLES 11 sp2 is webkit 0.2 and is very bugy.

I tried to remove the window with devilspie (http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15612342/dir/opensuse_11.x/com/devilspie-0.22-10.1.i586.rpm.html) but it does nothing. I was able to install it and set de .ds files but they have no effect.

I started the program with:

```
devilspie -d -a
Devil's Pie 0.22 starting...
Loading /etc/devilspie
Loading /root/.devilspie
Loading /root/.devilspie/flashplayer.ds
1 s-expression loaded.
```

The "flashplayer.ds":

```
(if (is (application_name) "flashplayer")
  (begin
    (undecorate)
  )
)
```

When I search for active windows with `xlsclients` it shows me that output:

```
# xlsclients
SLES11-SP2 xterm
SLES11-SP2 /usr/bin/xconsole -notify -nostdin -verbose -exitOnFail
SLES11-SP2 flashplayer
```

So the `application_name` must match.

Any idea to resolv it with `devilspie` or an other "trick"?

Comment: What Window Manager and/or Desktop Environment do you use? Why don't you install another browser?

Comment: There is x server on it. We build an application with mono and we tried a lot to get an other browser like chromium embedded http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/ but nothing works on that distribution... horrible.. I found something here: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=6128 maybe something like this is on SLES possible?

Comment: What **window manager** (and desktop environment if any) are you using? E.g. KDE, Unity, XFCE, twm, awesome, …

Comment: The administrator told me that it is Xorg.